User processes and sessions not terminated
I have vulnerability scans that are running on ubuntu 20.04 when the scanning account logs in and finishes its checks, the processes stay in a sleep mode on the systems. This is causing the system to have high cpu usage and sometimes it even forces the system to be rebooted. Any suggestions as to why this is happening? We have not change any of the default settings of the systems.
Thank you in advance.

What is doing the scanning? Is it an app or a command, and if so what is it?

So, we noticed that it is just anything. I ran a curl command last week and it completed. After looking at the process, it was discovered that it was in a sleep state.

A process in sleep is by definition not using any CPU (until it wakes up, anyway)

Having so many process is causing the CPU to spike.

Please post "Having so many process is causing the CPU to spike." as an  answer to your own question.
